# Stripe Subscription using stripe.Subscription.create function does not provide client_secret with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, stripe-payments

As suggested [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements) , I am using stripe.Subscription.create function to create a subscription for the users in my Django DRM and expect to have a client secret that is associated with the subscription and the related payment_intent.

However following is the error that I get :

```
customer.clientsecret=stripe_subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client_secret'

Below is the code that I am executing in the backend :

```
stripe_customer = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
customer.product = Product.objects.get(plan=0) # Free plan price id
customer.stripe_customer_id = stripe_customer['id']
stripe_subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=customer.stripe_customer_id,
                items=[{"price": customer.product.stripe_plan_id},],
                payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
                payment_settings={'save_default_payment_method': 'on_subscription'},
                expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
)
customer.clientsecret=stripe_subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret
```

Here below is the definition for Customer model :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    clientsecret = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    @property
    def get_created_date(self):
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(self.stripe_subscription_id)
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription.created)

    @property
    def get_next_billing_date(self):
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(self.stripe_subscription_id)
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription.current_period_end)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

The customers are created and associated with users when a new user signs up :

```
def post_save_customer_create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    ...
```

And here is the question : "How can I get a valid client_secret for the subscription that I create ?"

The value of the stripe_subscription is as below, and as you can see that latest_invoice is there, but payment_intent is null :

```
{
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "billing_cycle_anchor": 1677632660,
  "billing_thresholds": null,
  "cancel_at": null,
  "cancel_at_period_end": false,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1677632660,
  "currency": "usd",
  "current_period_end": 1680311060,
  "current_period_start": 1677632660,
  "customer": "cus_NRX9a1XQtjWJPd",
  "days_until_due": null,
  "default_payment_method": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "default_tax_rates": [],
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "id": "sub_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCOTRj2dLw",
  "items": {
    "data": [
      {
        "billing_thresholds": null,
        "created": 1677632660,
        "id": "si_NRXAdvOPbsuzfz",
        "metadata": {},
        "object": "subscription_item",
        "plan": {
          "active": true,
          "aggregate_usage": null,
          "amount": 0,
          "amount_decimal": "0",
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1673957019,
          "currency": "usd",
          "id": "price_1MRDt9LS6SANVcyCvUMav5Fr",
          "interval": "month",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": "Free",
          "object": "plan",
          "product": "prod_NBb5jZ3Sg3Knrl",
          "tiers": null,
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed"
        },
        "price": {
          "active": true,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1673957019,
          "currency": "usd",
          "custom_unit_amount": null,
          "id": "price_1MRDt9LS6SANVcyCvUMav5Fr",
          "livemode": false,
          "lookup_key": null,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": "Free",
          "object": "price",
          "product": "prod_NBb5jZ3Sg3Knrl",
          "recurring": {
            "aggregate_usage": null,
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed"
          },
          "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_quantity": null,
          "type": "recurring",
          "unit_amount": 0,
          "unit_amount_decimal": "0"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCOTRj2dLw",
        "tax_rates": []
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCOTRj2dLw"
  },
  "latest_invoice": {
    "account_country": "GB",
    "account_name": "Su Technology Ltd",
    "account_tax_ids": null,
    "amount_due": 0,
    "amount_paid": 0,
    "amount_remaining": 0,
    "amount_shipping": 0,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "attempt_count": 0,
    "attempted": true,
    "auto_advance": false,
    "automatic_tax": {
      "enabled": false,
      "status": null
    },
    "billing_reason": "subscription_create",
    "charge": null,
    "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
    "created": 1677632660,
    "currency": "usd",
    "custom_fields": null,
    "customer": "cus_NRX9a1XQtjWJPd",
    "customer_address": null,
    "customer_email": "bulkanutku@gmail.com",
    "customer_name": null,
    "customer_phone": null,
    "customer_shipping": null,
    "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
    "customer_tax_ids": [],
    "default_payment_method": null,
    "default_source": null,
    "default_tax_rates": [],
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "discounts": [],
    "due_date": null,
    "ending_balance": 0,
    "footer": null,
    "from_invoice": null,
    "hosted_invoice_url": "https://invoice.stripe.com/i/acct_1GJetwLS6SANVcyC/test_YWNjdF8xR0pldHdMUzZTQU5WY3lDLF9OUlhBQjBaaVZMQk5FSFFFcTBydVB5bzNpVnlORWk1LDY4MTczNDYw0200gE9zTwdN?s=ap",
    "id": "in_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCtGvBkugu",
    "invoice_pdf": "https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/acct_1GJetwLS6SANVcyC/test_YWNjdF8xR0pldHdMUzZTQU5WY3lDLF9OUlhBQjBaaVZMQk5FSFFFcTBydVB5bzNpVnlORWk1LDY4MTczNDYw0200gE9zTwdN/pdf?s=ap",
    "last_finalization_error": null,
    "latest_revision": null,
    "lines": {
      "data": [
        {
          "amount": 0,
          "amount_excluding_tax": 0,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "1 \u00d7 (at $0.00 / month)",
          "discount_amounts": [],
          "discountable": true,
          "discounts": [],
          "id": "il_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCTgQ4Jyt4",
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "object": "line_item",
          "period": {
            "end": 1680311060,
            "start": 1677632660
          },
          "plan": {
            "active": true,
            "aggregate_usage": null,
            "amount": 0,
            "amount_decimal": "0",
            "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
            "created": 1673957019,
            "currency": "usd",
            "id": "price_1MRDt9LS6SANVcyCvUMav5Fr",
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {},
            "nickname": "Free",
            "object": "plan",
            "product": "prod_NBb5jZ3Sg3Knrl",
            "tiers": null,
            "tiers_mode": null,
            "transform_usage": null,
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed"
          },
          "price": {
            "active": true,
            "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
            "created": 1673957019,
            "currency": "usd",
            "custom_unit_amount": null,
            "id": "price_1MRDt9LS6SANVcyCvUMav5Fr",
            "livemode": false,
            "lookup_key": null,
            "metadata": {},
            "nickname": "Free",
            "object": "price",
            "product": "prod_NBb5jZ3Sg3Knrl",
            "recurring": {
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "interval": "month",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
            "tiers_mode": null,
            "transform_quantity": null,
            "type": "recurring",
            "unit_amount": 0,
            "unit_amount_decimal": "0"
          },
          "proration": false,
          "proration_details": {
            "credited_items": null
          },
          "quantity": 1,
          "subscription": "sub_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCOTRj2dLw",
          "subscription_item": "si_NRXAdvOPbsuzfz",
          "tax_amounts": [],
          "tax_rates": [],
          "type": "subscription",
          "unit_amount_excluding_tax": "0"
        }
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "object": "list",
      "total_count": 1,
      "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCtGvBkugu/lines"
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {},
    "next_payment_attempt": null,
    "number": "E86AFCCB-0313",
    "object": "invoice",
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "paid": true,
    "paid_out_of_band": false,
    "payment_intent": null,
    "payment_settings": {
      "default_mandate": null,
      "payment_method_options": null,
      "payment_method_types": null
    },
    "period_end": 1677632660,
    "period_start": 1677632660,
    "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
    "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
    "quote": null,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "rendering_options": null,
    "shipping_cost": null,
    "shipping_details": null,
    "starting_balance": 0,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "status": "paid",
    "status_transitions": {
      "finalized_at": 1677632660,
      "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
      "paid_at": 1677632660,
      "voided_at": null
    },
    "subscription": "sub_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCOTRj2dLw",
    "subtotal": 0,
    "subtotal_excluding_tax": 0,
    "tax": null,
    "tax_percent": null,
    "test_clock": null,
    "total": 0,
    "total_discount_amounts": [],
    "total_excluding_tax": 0,
    "total_tax_amounts": [],
    "transfer_data": null,
    "webhooks_delivered_at": 1677632660
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
  "object": "subscription",
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "pause_collection": null,
  "payment_settings": {
    "payment_method_options": null,
    "payment_method_types": null,
    "save_default_payment_method": "on_subscription"
  },
  "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
  "pending_setup_intent": "seti_1Mge5gLS6SANVcyCiD2a3pQM",
  "pending_update": null,
  "plan": {
    "active": true,
    "aggregate_usage": null,
    "amount": 0,
    "amount_decimal": "0",
    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
    "created": 1673957019,
    "currency": "usd",
    "id": "price_1MRDt9LS6SANVcyCvUMav5Fr",
    "interval": "month",
    "interval_count": 1,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {},
    "nickname": "Free",
    "object": "plan",
    "product": "prod_NBb5jZ3Sg3Knrl",
    "tiers": null,
    "tiers_mode": null,
    "transform_usage": null,
    "trial_period_days": null,
    "usage_type": "licensed"
  },
  "quantity": 1,
  "schedule": null,
  "start_date": 1677632660,
  "status": "active",
  "tax_percent": null,
  "test_clock": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "trial_end": null,
  "trial_settings": {
    "end_behavior": {
      "missing_payment_method": "create_invoice"
    }
  },
  "trial_start": null
}
```

Comment: What is `customer` in your code? I recommend logging the value of `stripe_subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret` to confirm the Subscription is being created as expected and then setting a different variable name for client secret. See the Python code example here:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements#create-subscription

Comment: I have updated the question with Customer model, I have also shared log of stripe_subscription, client_secret is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and as you can see that latest_invoice is there, but payment_intent is null

Because the Invoice is for $0 so there is nothing to pay, so no PaymentIntent.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can use the `pending_setup_intent` instead and the `client_secret` of that object on the frontend with `stripe.confirmCardSetup(...)` to collect payment details without charging them.

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#using-setupintents